# Error ng-repeat Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Tengo el siguiente json object

```
$scope.datos = {
    "status":200,
    "data":{
        "username":"username1",
        "nombre": "Diego",
        "apellido": "Moreno Leon",
        "telefono": "999999",
        "celular": "000009901661",
        "email": "dimoreno3@gmail.com",
        "tipo_usuario": 1,
        "empresas": [
            {
                "id_empresa": 1,
                "nombre_emp": "Hotel Libertador",
                "email": "hllib@info.com",
                "calle_principal": "Av. Eduardo Kingman",
                "calle_secundaria": "Catamayo",
                "barrio": "Los Arupos",
                "numero_casa": "14-14",
                "latitud":"-11212121331",
                "longitud":"2122112122"
            },
            {
                "id_empresa": 2,
                "nombre_emp": "Hotel Loja",
                "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                "numero_casa": "60-45",
                "latitud":"-34444444444",
                "longitud":"21111111"
            }
        ],
        "categorias": [
            {
                "id_categoria":1,
                "nombre_cat":"Gastronomia",
                "sitios":[
                    {
                        "id_empresa": 1,
                        "nombre_emp": "Bourbon",
                        "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                        "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                        "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                        "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                        "numero_casa": "60-45",
                        "latitud":"-34444444444",
                        "longitud":"21111111"                       
                    },
                    {
                        "id_empresa": 2,
                        "nombre_emp": "La Mojigata",
                        "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                        "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                        "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                        "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                        "numero_casa": "60-45",
                        "latitud":"-34444444444",
                        "longitud":"21111111"                       
                    },
                    {
                        "id_empresa": 3,
                        "nombre_emp": "Obelics",
                        "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                        "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                        "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                        "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                        "numero_casa": "60-45",
                        "latitud":"-34444444444",
                        "longitud":"21111111"                       
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id_categoria":2,
                "nombre_cat":"Deportes",
                "sitios":[
                    {
                        "id_empresa": 4,
                        "nombre_emp": "Coliseo Loja",
                        "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                        "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                        "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                        "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                        "numero_casa": "60-45",
                        "latitud":"-34444444444",
                        "longitud":"21111111"                       
                    },
                    {
                        "id_empresa": 5,
                        "nombre_emp": "Coliseo de Machala",
                        "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                        "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                        "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                        "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                        "numero_casa": "60-45",
                        "latitud":"-34444444444",
                        "longitud":"21111111"                       
                    },
                    {
                        "id_empresa": 6,
                        "nombre_emp": "Coliseo del Oro",
                        "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                        "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                        "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                        "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                        "numero_casa": "60-45",
                        "latitud":"-34444444444",
                        "longitud":"21111111"                       
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id_categoria":3,
                "nombre_cat":"Transporte",
                "sitios":[
                    {
                        "id_empresa": 7,
                        "nombre_emp": "Sur Oriente",
                        "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                        "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                        "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                        "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                        "numero_casa": "60-45",
                        "latitud":"-34444444444",
                        "longitud":"21111111"                       
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id_categoria":4,
                "nombre_cat":"Bares",
                "sitios":[
                    {
                        "id_empresa": 8,
                        "nombre_emp": "La Pupila",
                        "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                        "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                        "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                        "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                        "numero_casa": "60-45",
                        "latitud":"-34444444444",
                        "longitud":"21111111"                       
                    },
                    {
                        "id_empresa": 9,
                        "nombre_emp": "Coyote Bar",
                        "email": "hlloja@info.com",
                        "calle_principal": "Av. Pio Jaramillo",
                        "calle_secundaria": "Meradillo",
                        "barrio": "San Sebastian",
                        "numero_casa": "60-45",
                        "latitud":"-34444444444",
                        "longitud":"21111111"                       
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

y lo deseo mostrar de la siguiente manera

```
<ul ng-repeat="i in datos">
    <li>{{$index}}</li>
    <li><input type="button" value="{{i.username}}"></li>
  </ul>
```

Pero al mostrar en mi vista html se me presenta dos botones el primero con valor vacio y el segundo con el valor de username, lo que deseo saber es como presento solo el valor de username sin que se repitan los valores vacios de antemano les agradezco.

Datos adicionales trabajo con bootstrap y con la version de angularjs : 1.5.8

Answer (score 1):

En [la documentación](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) dice que para utilizar la directiva de ngRepeat se usa bajo la nomenclatura:

```
<li ng-repeat="modelo in coleccion"></li>
```

donde `modelo` es el nombre que iterará en `coleccion`. Siendo `coleccion` del tipo **arreglo**.

Por tanto en tu JSON si sólo quieres mostrar los datos, la directiva para enlazar el modelo a la vista que puedes usar es `ng-bind` de la siguiente forma:

```
<span ng-bind="datos.username"></span>
```

Más adelante si quieres agregar funcionalidad con funciones puedes hacer:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-bind="datos.username" ng-click="cambiarNombre( datos.username )"></button>
```

Fíjate como utilizo la directiva de ng-click para asignarle una función que está en el scope y le paso por parámetro el username que contiene datos.

Saludos